# Comparing packets in Python

Tags: python, sniffing

I'm trying to compare sniffed packets. I have to compare the `src` address with the previous, and the same with the `dst` address.
This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python
from scapy.all import *

pkt = sniff(filter="ip",timeout=5)
for p in pkt:
    try:
        if IP in pkt:
            ip_src=pkt[IP].src
            ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
                if (pkt[IP].src[p]!=pkt[IP].src[p+1])
                    packet=pkt[IP].src
                    return packet
                    print "packets not equal"
```

But this doesn't seem right. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well it isn't a complete valid Python program....

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few problems here, mostly in your Python syntax. 
1) An "if" statement in python looks like the following:

`if 1 == 1:
    print "Hello World!"`

2) Notice that you try to use the `print` command after you use `return`. This will not work because once you use return the function will finish running. For example: 

`def test():
    return "Hello world" #Will run and exit the function
    print "Hello wolrd2!" #Will not run since the function was finished on the line above`

After you have fixed these problems I suggest you look over your code and fix it to the right Python syntax.

Comment: I still have a problem with `if (pkt[IP].src[p]!=pkt[IP].src[p+1])` ..it give me this error: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: If you look at your code, notice that you have an indent (4 spaces) before your "if" statement. The error indicates that those indents should not be there. Delete it and the error will go way. (Have your if statement aligned with the line above it)